# operator* of std::complex returns different answer than manual formula of complex number multiplication

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I'm running the following code:

```
complex<int16_t> num1 (953, -20068);
complex<int16_t> num2 (953, -20068);
complex<int32_t> result;
result = num1*num2;
std::cout << to_string(result.real()) << "+" << to_string(result.imag())  << "i"<< std::endl;
```

I get the following result:

```
-15199+23416i
```

But if I calculate the multiplication according to the formula of multiplication of complex numbers:

```
complex<int16_t> num1 (953, -20068);
complex<int16_t> num2 (953, -20068);

int32_t A = ((num1.real())*(num2.real()))-((num1.imag())*(num2.imag()));
int32_t B = ((num1.real())*(num2.imag()))+((num2.real())*(num1.imag()));

std::cout << to_string(A) << to_string(B)  << "i"<< std::endl;
```

I get the following result:

```
-401816415-38249608i
```

My question is why the formula of multiplying complex numbers returns a different result from that of the oprator* (of the type std::complex)?

Comment: Because `int16_t` can only hold values from -32768 to 32767. Change the type to `complex<int32_t>` and it works fine

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but those calls to `to_string` aren’t needed. The stream inserter does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your complex numbers are of type `complex<int16_t>`, meaning the real and imaginary parts are both 16 bits. The result of multiplying them must also have real and imaginary parts of 16 bits. This happens before you store the result into a `complex<int32_t>`.

When you do the multiplication yourself, the 16 bit values are first converted to `int`s (which are likely 32 bits on your system). Thus your results aren't truncated when you put them into `int32_t`s.

You can fix this by using `complex<int32_t>` values all around, or by doing the multiplication using `complex<int32_t>`s instead:

```
result = complex<int32_t>(num1) * complex<int32_t>(num2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs are `int16_t`, so you're most likely getting overflow, since the result will also be `int16_t`. Only after the result has been calculated will it be converted into an `int32_t`.

If you change your inputs to `std::complex<int32_t>` the result will be correct.